# Hibernate table is not mapped but tables exist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I have a project that use Hibernate but I've got an error table is not mapped.

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TrainingRoom is not mapped [SELECT DISTINCT t FROM TrainingRoom t ORDER BY t.id]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:77)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:220)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:175)
...
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TrainingRoom is not mapped [SELECT DISTINCT t FROM TrainingRoom t ORDER BY t.id]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TrainingRoom is not mapped [SELECT DISTINCT t FROM TrainingRoom t ORDER BY t.id]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
...
```

This is my TrainingRoom.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ppp_trainingRoom")
public class TrainingRoom {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String roomName;

    //GET SET Method

}
```

TrainingRoomEndpoint.java

```
@Stateless
@Path("/trainingRoom")
public class TrainingRoomEndpoint {

    @Inject
    TrainingRoomService trainingRoomService;

    @GET
    @Path("/listAll")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response listAll(@Context HttpServletRequest request,     @QueryParam("start") Integer startPosition, @QueryParam("max") Integer     maxResult) {
        List<TrainingRoom> trainingRoomList =     trainingRoomService.listAll(startPosition, maxResult);
        return Response.status(200).entity(trainingRoomList).build();
    }
}
```

TrainingRoomService.java

```
public List<TrainingRoom> listAll(@QueryParam("start") Integer startPosition,
        @QueryParam("max") Integer maxResult) {
    logger.info(":: listAll ::");
    TypedQuery<TrainingRoom> findAllQuery = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT DISTINCT t FROM TrainingRoom t ORDER BY t.id", TrainingRoom.class);
    if( startPosition != null ) {
        findAllQuery.setFirstResult(startPosition);
    }
    if( maxResult != null ) {
        findAllQuery.setMaxResults(maxResult);
    }
    final List<TrainingRoom> results = findAllQuery.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

Before I stuck at this error, I have 2 EntityManagers because I have some tables that are Synonym. But I found that it does not have to. So I deleted it and I got stuck like error above.

How could I fix this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why did you write this `@Table(name = "ppp_trainingRoom")`?

Comment: is your table named `ppp_trainingRoom` with an uppercase R ? some databases (postgres) hate uppercase tables.

Comment: Make sure the JPA implementation can see the class `TrainingRoom`. Posting the structure of the project & persistence.xml might help.

Comment: Can you show your persistence file?

Comment: @StephaneM Sorry for that. The database I using has underscore_case but I prefered camelCase.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Yes, I had changed it to ppp_trainingroom but the error still remain.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Here http://collabedit.com/e2wyp

Comment: @GarimaGupta This is persistence.xml http://collabedit.com/dsynw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add the new property :

```
 <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
```

or you can specify the class tag for each class under the persistence unit tag:

```
<class>org.cmh.itsetup.model.TrainingRoom</class>
```